# Mysql not exists or an alternative

Tags: mysql, sql

An example of a table, data along with the query can be found in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e65dd/3

I'm interested in finding all distinct user_id's that don't have certain record_type.

In my actual case, this table is huge and it has several million records in it and have an index on user_id column. Although i'm planning to retrieve it in batches by limiting the output to 1000 at a time.

```
select distinct user_id from 
records o where 
not exists (
    select * 
    from records i 
    where i.user_id=o.user_id and i.record_type=3) 
limit 0, 1000
```

Is there a better approach to achieve this need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM records) AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN records as r
  ON u.user_id = r.user_id AND r.record_type = 3
WHERE r.user_id IS NULL
```

That avoids the correlated subquery in your NOT EXISTS solution.

Alternatively, you should have another table that just lists users, so you don't have to do the subquery:

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM users AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN records as r
  ON u.user_id = r.user_id AND r.record_type = 3
WHERE r.user_id IS NULL
```

In either case, it would help optimize the JOIN to add a compound index on the pair of columns:

```
ALTER TABLE records ADD KEY (user_id, record_type)
```

Comment: When I tested, adding the indexes was the only thing that mattered. All variations of the query ran at the same speed otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I's suggest a join as well, but mine would have differed from Bill K's like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.user_id 
FROM records AS r 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM records WHERE record_type = 3) AS rt3users
   ON r.user_id = rt3users.user_id
WHERE rt3users.user_id IS NULL
;
```

However, an alternative I would not expect better performance from, but is worth checking, since performance can vary based on size and content of data...

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.user_id 
FROM records AS r 
WHERE r.user_id NOT IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
   FROM records 
   WHERE record_type = 3
)
;
```

Note, this one is more similar to your original but does away with the correlated nature of the original subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table with record types equal 3 like

```
Select distinct user_id
into #users
from records
where record_type=3
```

Then create unique index (or primary key) on this table. Then you query would search indexes in both tables.

I can’t say the performance would be better you’d have to test it on your data.